# Xamarin Forms: Auto fill the city,state and zipcode as per the user input

Tags: xamarin.forms

Need to show the details of the city, state, and zipcode as per the user input on my mobile app.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

If a user enters a letter, all the location which matches the entry should be shown. In the website this one is possible with google API, and how to do the same in a mobile app?
Thanks Advance

Update @G.Mich

Sorry for the late update.

I have tried this but getting following errors related to `GoogleMaps`. I have installed `Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps` nuget package.

[image]

> The type or namespace name 'Position' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

This example about Google Maps Place Search in Xamarin Forms is very helpful and one of the most latest

https://www.xamboy.com/2019/05/29/google-maps-place-search-in-xamarin-forms/

similar article and full code here

https://www.xamboy.com/2019/07/03/introducing-xuber-uber-clone-using-xamarin-forms/

Comment: I hope it helps you !!

Comment: I have edited the question with some error logs, can you please have a look.